# Rearranging dataframes in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe similar to this

```
df <- data.frame (month = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "01", "03"),
                  Year= c("01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02"),
                  value= c("12", "20", "34", "18", "22", "27")
                  )
```

However I want the columns to be the unique months (ranging from 01-12) and the rows to be years respective values. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = month, values_from = value)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to this: You describe a table, you can make a table from a data frame using a formula with the [?xtabs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/xtabs.html) function.  Unfortunately, I can't get it to use the `value` column as a 'response'.  So I simply replicated each row the number of times given by the `value`.  Consider:

```
(tab <- xtabs(~Year+month, df[rep(1:6, times=df$value),]))
#     month
# Year 01 02 03 04
#   01  1  3  6  2
#   02  4  0  5  0
```

In your question, you refer to months 1-12, but only 4 are listed in the example.  It isn't clear if you want to be able to add extra columns of 0's as well.  You can use [?cbind](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html) to add a matrix of 0's, and then create names with [?colnames](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html).  Consider:

```
(tab <- cbind(tab, matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=8)))
#    01 02 03 04                
# 01  1  3  6  2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 02  4  0  5  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
colnames(tab) <- c(paste0(0,1:9), "10","11","12")
tab
#    01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
# 01  1  3  6  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 02  4  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```